# How to Copy the one Cell Format to the all the Cells beside that Cell?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Could you guide me by saying that How can i Copy the color and Font and Style of an Cell say in Row#1? But not the content of the Cell.I wrote the below code but it gets copied all the above with First Cell data,which I wouldn't expect.

```
        ob3.Range("A1").Copy
    ob3.Range("A1").EntireRow.PasteSpecial(-4163) 'xlValues
```

Please guide here!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the follwing:

```
ob3.Range("A1").Copy 
ob3.Range("A1").EntireRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) 
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I see Scott's point here :) Either you could set the number itself or use a `const` to use this formattig via your sheet.

```
Const xlPasteFormats = -4122 
Const xlPasteValues = -4163

ob3.Range("A1").Copy
ob3.Range("A1").EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: you'll need to give him the associated numerical value, as vbScript cannot read `xlPasteFormats`, but it can read whatever the enumeration is.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I find it out from Excel VBA documentation,So no problem :-) it is `-4122`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman +1 and thank you :) Tukai, I am not sure if it's `-4105`, it says it's `-4122`